# Messaging Centre - Subscribing Event in the ViewModel Constructor

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm-light

I am trying to send data from one ViewModel to another using Messaging Centre.
I have subscribed the event in 2nd ViewModel's constructor. But the event is not subscribed as the constructor is not compiled until I open the page/view  corresponding to the ViewModel.

I am using MVVM Light, until now I had an understanding that the VM's constructor are compiled when ViewModelLocator is called at the app startup.

Can someone help me understand this better and how can I subscribe the event i.e. compile the constructor without the VM being called.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are thinking about this in the wrong way. Without seeing code it's difficult to see what you are trying to achieve exactly, but what you could do is subscribe to the event elsewhere in your app, for example in your App.xaml.cs. When the event fires, at that point navigate to a new page of type ViewModel2 and pass any details required as a navigation parameter.